# Define new :first-child after current one was removed / moved

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that removes list element from one ordered list then finds all ordered lists after current one, gets their first element and appends it to that lists previous one.

The issue: if I remove first element from any list or it is appended function stops working, I believe it is due jQuery remembering what first element was and as it is no longer in its place it can't find it, however it should just re-define / look up new element in particular list that is first child at the moment. Here is the function:

```
function removeQueueItem(element) {
    //Get ordered list of removed list element
    var itemMonth = element.parents().eq(2); //li.queue-month
        //Get all following lists
        nextMonths = itemMonth.nextAll('.queue-month');

    //Fade out removed element
    element.parent().fadeOut(function(index){
        //Remove element from DOM
        element.remove();

        nextMonths.each(function(index) {
            //Check if next month has socks
            if($(this).find('.item-dragable').length > 0) {
                var firstItem = $(this).find('.item-dragable:first-child');
                $(this).prev().find('ol').append(firstItem);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kLyxqhj/5/) - Remove first item in September then remove any item in August, the first item in September should become pink, but it isn't happening. This is what the problem is.

Comment: Please add a jsFiddle, we need to see the markup as well

Comment: @YotamOmer added it in, just remove one item from a month, you will see first item in next one go pink, remove pink item, and than remove any item from first month again and this functionality doesn't work anymore

Comment: @YotamOmer Remove first item in September, after remove any item in August, First item in September should become pink, but it doesn't for me.

Comment: @YotamOmer if you don't remove first item before, than it works, but it should also look up new first item after

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are removing an `a` tag instead of a `li` tag. So when you search `:first-child` it is there, but you do not see it.
In order to make it work you need to change your code from:

```
element.parent().fadeOut(function(index){
    //Remove element from DOM
    element.remove(); <-- here

    ...
});
```

To:

```
element.parent().fadeOut(function(index){
    //Remove element from DOM
    $(this).remove(); <-- element to $(this)

    ...
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kLyxqhj/10/)

Comment: Better answer than mine; I hadn't even considered using `$(this)` - I must be getting rusty with jQuery! +1

Answer (score 2):

That's because it's the `parent` you're fading out, but the inner `element` you're removing. Your `.item-dragable` element still exists and ends up with its `display` property set to `none`. This means it's still the first child.

[image: Example Before]

...becomes:

[image: Example After]

To fix this, simply change:

```
element.remove()
```

...to:

```
element.parent().remove()
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1kLyxqhj/9/).

Comment: For better scalability, it is better to address to the element using `$(this)`